# Touch slide input for jQuery gallery

Tags: jquery, touch, slide

I have created a HTML5 gallery for my website using this jQuery slider plugin (http://slidesjs.com/). Is it possible to add support to the gallery to accept a touch slide input from smart phones in order to activate the slide transitions?

Or would it be the case that a mobile version of the web page would need to be developed specific to smart phones and tablets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it's [Hammer](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) time.

Comment: Many thanks. Great suggestion. I also found RoyalSlider very useful. (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/)

Comment: Furthermore, FlexSlider from WooThemes now has touch gesture support.

Answer (score 0):

Free touch swipe slider [Master Slider](http://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider/)